# Replace value with different value for multi level column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('Quarter', 'Range'): {0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, ('Q1(0.25)', 'Low'): {0: 0, 1: 0}, ('Q1(0.25)', 'High'): {0: 10, 1: 630}, ('Q2(0.5)', 'Low'): {0: 10, 1: 630}, ('Q2(0.5)', 'High'): {0: 50, 1: 3000}, ('Q3(0.75)', 'Low'): {0: 50, 1: 3000}, ('Q3(0.75)', 'High'): {0: 100, 1: 8500}, ('Q4(1.0)', 'Low'): {0: 100, 1: 8500}, ('Q4(1.0)', 'High'): {0: 'np.inf', 1: 'np.inf'}})
```

As the above dataframe if the value of column A is between 0-10 replace the value with 0.25, if the value is between 10-50 replace the value with 0.5. Similarly, we have to repeat for all values and columns.

**Expected output:**

If the value is 12 for A and 3210 for column B.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, 'Prob': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.75}})
```

How to do it?

Comment: What is `print (df1.to_dict())` for first DataFrame?

Comment: Can you use copyable plain text instead of pictures? That would make working on your problem much easier.

Comment: df.to_dict() is
{'Quarter': {0: 'Range', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}, 'Q1(0.25)': {0: 'Low', 1: 0, 2: 0}, 'Unnamed: 2': {0: 'High', 1: 10, 2: 630}, 'Q2(0.5)': {0: 'Low', 1: 10, 2: 630}, 'Unnamed: 4': {0: 'High', 1: 50, 2: 3000}, 'Q3(0.75)': {0: 'Low', 1: 50, 2: 3000}, 'Unnamed: 6': {0: 'High', 1: 100, 2: 8500}, 'Q4(1.0)': {0: 'Low', 1: 100, 2: 8500}, 'Unnamed: 8': {0: 'High', 1: 'np.inf', 2: 'np.inf'}}

Comment: that is multi-level column if I use to_dict it is showing Unnamed, so I pasted the picture, will try to change

Comment: How is created first `df` ? From file? By `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1])` for read MultiIndex ?

Comment: edited the question in the required format